# Content script file not visible in addon debugger

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've created an addon using the addon SDK and installed it in Firefox (version 35.0.1). The addon has the following files -

- data/login.js (content script file)
- lib/main.js (main addon code)
- test/test-main.js (auto-generated)
- package.json

In the main addon code I'm creating a panel, and the content script file is loaded using the contentScriptFile property of the panel. However when I launch the addon debugger, I'm able to see only the main.js script and not the content script. I've checked that the xpi file actually contains the content script file. So why isn't the debugger showing it?

Comment: Can you add your code? Do you see errors? You may, for example, have a syntax error in your content script.

Comment: I have the same problem. Not only is the content script not showing, the content style file is also not showing, nor in Debugger, nor in Inspector styles, both neither in Brower Toolbox as the normal developer tools.  Note though: Both script ánd stylesheet are working fine, I just can't debug/fiddle with them.  (Using Firefox Developer edition.)  I am guessing towards a configuration setting or bug.

Comment: you have to use the Web developer Tool see post below by e-motiv

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [browser toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox) or the *browser content toolbox* which is not scoped to a single addon.

Afaik the addon debugger only shows scripts running in the same compartment as the addon main, which may miss scripts running in sandboxes/other compartments.

Comment: The browser toolbox isn't showing it either. What's a compartment?

Comment: compartments are different javascript contexts inside firefox. anyway, if the browser toolbox doesn't show it it might not have been loaded yet. open the panel first before trying to look for the script

Comment: I'm also having this problem, the debugger; statement doesn't work, and, unlike elements on the main page, the right click 'inspect Element' menu item also doesn't work on html elements in the addon panel! I also looked in the about:memory page and it looks like the panel is running in its own memory compartment

Comment: panels are a pain to debug, try disabling their autohide property, that might make it a little easier

Comment: "To do this, open the Developer Tools Settings, go to the section "Advanced Settings", and check the settings "Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes" and "Enable remote debugging"." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox

Answer (score 2):

I think I found it (using Firefox Developer Edition 42.0a2 though).

1. Open the Default **Web developer Tools** (Ctrl+shift+I)
2. Go to **Settings** (cog wheel top right)
3. Enable "Advanced Settings" > **"Enable worker debugging (in development)"**
4. Enable "Inspector" > **"Show Browser styles"** (for seeing your content style (files))
5. Reload the page
   [image: Screenshot]

Comment: It should be noted that to see your source code in the Web developer Tool you have to click on the debugger tab, and scroll down the all the source code files listed on the tab on the left, it will be there somewhere. It if doesn't appear then you have make a break point and step through code until the source file in question is loaded then it will appear in the scroll box. Alternatively you can write your extension for chrome and do the debugging there, its easier!, then migrate to Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably an error in your content script code that prevents the file from appearing in the debugger file list. I had this problem and it's difficult to find these errors as the Firefox error log often doesn't refer to the which file is in error or the line number. Check for unpaired braces that kind of thing

Comment: Seems simple but once I commented out my entire code file minus a few var declarations, it appeared. Good answer.